# Is there a way to use absolute and relative positions for series in QML ChartView?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to ensure that in the following code, the red line is always on top, does qml have any features that would allow me to do this, such as a relative or absolute positing option.

```
ChartView{
    anchors.fill: parent
    id: chart

    ValueAxis{
        id: axisY
        min: 0
        max: 1
    }
    ValueAxis{
        id: axisX
        min: 0
        max: 1
    }

    property var redSeries;
    property var blackSeries;

    Component.onCompleted: {
        redSeries = chart.createSeries(chart.SeriesTypeLine, "red", axisX, axisY);
        redSeries.color = "red";
        redSeries.append(0.3,0);
        redSeries.append(0.3,1);
        redSeries.width = 3;
    }

    Timer{
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        triggeredOnStart : false

        onTriggered: {

            chart.blackSeries = chart.createSeries(chart.SeriesTypeLine, "black", axisX, axisY);
            chart.blackSeries.color = "black";
            chart.blackSeries.append(0,0.5);
            chart.blackSeries.append(1,0.5);
            chart.blackSeries.width = 3;
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

What's being displayed at the moment is what's in the first image, however I want the second image to be displayed while still generating the second black line after the red line

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to provide your try to implement the issue with desired behaveor. Some code, sketchup ...whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get that ready

Comment: @folibis I've added some code, and described what I want in better detail

Comment: Ok, your y axis is from 0(min) to 1(max) and you are trying do draw red line from 0 to 1 ie.from max to min. How do you want it will be on the top? Either you are not quite correctly asked a question, or you do not fully understand how to build graphics.

Comment: Hi @folibis, I apologise if I wasn't clear previously, I've updated the question and have now provided with an image of what I want and what I have, if comparing it to pure graphics it would be similar to changing the Z-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the misunderstanding. I've thought about 'top' as top of y axis, not as 'z' -). As for the issue I didn't found any solution. There is no any way to control z-order of the series. The only stupid workaround I see is to delete the red line and to add it after all time you add the black one.

May be like this:

```
ChartView {
    ...
    Timer {
        ... 
        onTriggered: {
            chart.blackSeries = chart.createSeries(chart.SeriesTypeLine, "black", axisX, axisY);

            ...

            chart.removeSeries(chart.redSeries);
        }
    }
    onSeriesRemoved: {
        var newSeries = chart.createSeries(chart.SeriesTypeLine, "red", axisX, axisY);
        newSeries.color = "red";
        for(var i = 0;i <series.count;i ++)
        {
            var p = series.at(i);
            newSeries.append(p.x, p.y);
        }
        chart.redSeries = newSeries;
    }
```